# c# conversion operator for class with recursive collection

Tags: c#, recursion, casting, implicit

I've been struggling to get a cast to work for a class that has a collection of itself. In testing with a root object that has two TypeA elements in the List, when the List does the implicit cast... it enters the conversion code for the TypeA element of the collection, and because this is the top of the tree, returns TypeAIntermediate without entering the foreach loop (that perfect 
- there's nothing in SomeAs). But when it returns the converted instance, it appears to start over at the top of the conversion code for the root like nothing happened.

As far as I can tell this never stops. I rewrote this simplified version that follows the same format... hopefully I didn't mess up.

```
//These are models used in a .Net 4.5 EF6 Library 
public class TypeA
{
    public string TypeAStuff;
    public TypeB JustOneB;
    public List<TypeA> SomeAs;


    public static implicit operator TypeAIntermediate(TypeA a)
    {
        //New up an Intermediate A to return.
        TypeAIntermediate aI = new TypeAIntermediate();
        //And get ready to do handle the collection... a few ways to do this.
        List<TypeAIntermediate> children = new List<TypeAIntermediate>();

        //...but this appears to create an infinite loop?
        foreach (TypeA item in a.SomeAs)
            children.Add(item); //Cast from TypeA to to TypeAIntermediate happens here but will just keeps cycling

        aI.TypeAStuff = a.TypeAStuff;
        aI.JustOneB = a.JustOneB;
        aI.SomeAs = children;
        return aI;
    }
}

public class TypeB
{
    public string TypeBStuff;

    public static implicit operator TypeBIntermediate(TypeB b)
    {
        TypeBIntermediate bI = new TypeBIntermediate();
        bI.TypeBStuff = b.TypeBStuff;
        return bI;
    }
}

//These Intermediate Classes live in a .Net35 Library - Unity cannot use Libraries compiled for later .Net Versions.
public class TypeAIntermediate
{
    public string TypeAStuff;
    public TypeBIntermediate JustOneB;
    public List<TypeAIntermediate> SomeAs;
}

public class TypeBIntermediate
{
    public string TypeBStuff;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing how this code would create an infinite loop.  Can you reproduce the problem with the simplified code?  If so can you include the code that builds up the `TypeA` class that get into an infinite loop when you try to convert it?  Also there's no recursion anywhere in this code sample.

Comment: I would think the implicit cast that occurs at children.Add(item) (from TypeA item to Children<TypeAIntermediate>) which forces the conversion operator to call itself again to do the implicit cast would count as recursion. But also, what do you call a Class that has members of itself, or member collections of itself (maybe not recursive - just actually curious)?

Comment: You don't have a collection of `TypeA` you have a collection of `TypeB`.  If you did have a collection of `TypeA` that was being converted then you would have recursion and you could get an infinite loop if two objects both had the other or even themselves inside of the collection.

Comment: Oops - I did mess this up. It's supposed to be a list of TypeA.

Comment: In the case of a collection of `TypeA` you'd need to keep track of which objects had been converted by creating a mapping from `TypeA` to `TypeAIntermediate`, then you could populate the collections of each created `TypeAIntermediate` by looking up the conversion in the map.  Assuming you want to perseve loops in your hierarchy.

Comment: I'll check to confirm that somehow the root did not end up back in it's own Collection; that is certainly the easiest answer.

Comment: "keep track of which objects had been converted by" - Shouldn't the foreach loop keep track of what has been converted?

Comment: Yes, but each time you cast you'll be looping over a new collection that might contain an object you've already converted and is part of a loop that will cause you to infinitely loop until you get a stack overflow.

Comment: I thought that was where you were going with it. Unfortunately I did confirm both entries in the collection have nothing in their collection. I don't believe the issue is the root appearing in it's own collection. Also it appears that when I thought I was stepping into the next iteration after the return is executed, it turns out I was just hitting my break point that was on the foreach loop line so at the moment all I really know is that the cast is being run on the root many many times. I'll have to look into it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can write that to avoid stack overflow if you have loops in your hierarchy.

```
public static implicit operator TypeAIntermediate(TypeA a)
{
    return Convert(a, new Dictionary<TypeA, TypeAIntermediate>());
}

private static TypeAIntermediate Convert(
    Type A a, 
    Dictionary<TypeA, TypeAIntermediate> lookup)
{
    TypeAIntermediate aI;
    if(lookup.TryGetValue(a, out aI))
    {
        return aI;
    }

    aI = new TypeAintermediate();
    lookup.Add(a, aI);

    List<TypeAIntermediate> children = new List<TypeAIntermediate>();
    foreach (TypeA item in a.SomeAs)
        children.Add(Convert(item, lookup)); 

    aI.TypeAStuff = a.TypeAStuff;
    aI.JustOneB = a.JustOneB;
    aI.SomeAs = children;
    return aI;
}
```

Basically by using a dictionary you can determine if any `TypeA` object already has a `TypeAIntermediate` object created for it in which case you don't need to create it again and just return the corresponding `TypeAIntermediate` reference.    If it hasn't then you create a new `TypeAIntermediate` and populate it's collection be recursively calling the `Create` method that also takes the dictionary.

Additionally if you have the same object reference twice in different branches this will only create one `TypeAIntermediate` reference instead of two.

Comment: So I can confirm we are only operating on three instances of this class. The root and two more (both with empty TypeA Lists) that are in the List of TypeAs on the root. I also confirmed that the conversion operator is only being called in one place, first by commenting out the line that does the cast with my break point in the still in the operator (it was not reached), then by re-enabling the line that does the cast with a break point on it. It was only reached once. ...but the odd loop behavior persisted in the conversion code.

Comment: I imagine I'll have to actually start experimenting with the simplified code. To answer you question, no I have not attempted it with this version of the code (but it's pretty similar to the real thing). I was just hoping someone would immediately recognize the problem. The root in it's own collection was a good call though - I was hoping you had it.

Comment: So... I built the original simplified code in a blank project... it runs fine. Something stranger is going on in my project I guess. ...There won't be a successful answer to my question based on the posted code (since I guess it works) so maybe this conversion loop detector thing will be useful to someone else. Thanks.